# single and double quotes in punctuation regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match all punctuation with a regex in javascript including single and double quotes, but whenever I run this regex I get -1 and the indexOf anything in this regex.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
" '".indexOf(/[.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\'\"\-_`~()]/g);
```

Why am I getting -1 for the index of the single quote if the single quote is in the regex?

Comment: `indexOf` doesn't accept a regex, use `match`

Comment: @anubhava I believe indexOf does accept regex. match returns the same that it can't be found.

Comment: @vks even without the space it doesn't match.

Comment: @wordSmith: *"I believe indexOf does accept regex"* You are [mistaken](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.indexof).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder clearly I am. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `match` function and get the index of matched element by specifying `index` key.

```
> " '".match(/[.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\'\"\-_`~()]/)['index'];
1
```

Comment: something I was doing before kept on returning null, but your example works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `test` to test a regex pattern against a string.

Example;

```
var string = " '";
var containPunctuation = /[.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\'\"\-_`~()]/g.test(string);

if (containPunctuation)
{
    //Do whatever you want
    console.log('It contains punctuation');
}
```

Comment: Could you please add details to clarify your answer?